# Springer template

Tags: springernature, springer

How can I reduce the white space on the right of the page?

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\usepackage{algorithm}
%%%\usepackage[linesnumbered, ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e} 

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{enumerate}
 
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stix,bbding,pifont,utfsym,fontawesome}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabu, colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
 \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} 
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 


\usepackage{tabu, colortbl}
      
%
\begin{document}


\section{CH sum}
Checksum error detection is a method used to identify errors in transmitted data. The 
process involves dividing the data into equally sized segments and using a 1’s 
complement to calculate the sum of these segments. The calculated sum is then sent along 
with the data to 
the receiver. At the receiver’s end, the same process is repeated and if all zeroes are 
obtained in the sum, it means that the data is correct.

Checksum – Operation at Sender’s Side
Firstly, the data is divided into k segments each of m bits.
On the sender’s end, the segments are added using 1’s complement arithmetic to get the 
sum. The sum is complemented to get the checksum.
The checksum segment is sent along with the data segments.
Checksum – Operation at Receiver’s Side
At the receiver’s end, all received segments are added using 1’s complement arithmetic 
to get the sum. The sum is complemented.
If the result is zero, the received data is accepted; otherwise discarded.
```

Comment: Where can the community gain access to `svjour3.cls` (and any accompanying resources)?

Comment: don't change the page size of a journal class the whole point is that it fits the paper used by the journal not the paper you use locally, so it may have strange margins in drafts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Ok, but I have a big white space between the sections, is that normal?

Comment: how can we tell if you show no example?  Your example has some code but is incomplete and produces no pdf output and has no sections so hard to say if anything is as expected or an error in your code. But you should never change the layout if you are submitting to springer it will just delay publication, and if you are not submitting to springer don't use their class.

Comment: By "the white space on the right of the page", do you mean the wide margin?

Comment: You include a large number of unused (and sometimes conflicting) packages. Can you reduce your code to use only the packages you need? For example, drop `algorithm`, `algorithm2e`, `algpseudocode`, `cite`, `lipsum`, `placeins`, `enumerte`, `url`, ... And there's no need to load packages like `xcolor` and `colortbl` more than once.

Comment: @Mico, Yes.....